# Pass a function that requires an argument to a child widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was looking for a way to change the active tab of `animated bottom navigation bar` without tapping on the bottom menu. Needed a way to create a `Back` button and a way to automatically change tabs after submitting a form.

I couldn't find a complete example of how to do this. Might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent Widget define your function as you'd normally do:

```
void selectedTab(index) {
    if (_bottomNavIndex != index) {
      setState(() {
        _bottomNavIndex = index;
      });
    }
  }
```

You then pass this function as an argument to your `Child` widget:

```
  Page5(
    selectedTab: selectedTab, // Notice it's not selectedTab()
  )
```

In your `Child` widget define the expected function:

```
 const Page5({Key? key,required this.selectedTab}) : super(key: key);
    
  //? Use type ValueSetter if passing a argument
  //? Use type ValueGtetter if you are not passing an argument but expecting a value to be returned
  //? Use type VoidCallback if not sending or receiving a value
  final ValueSetter<int> selectedTab;
```

The way you use any data/function passed to your `Child` widget is by using `widget`
You can then call this function by using `widget.functionName(argument)` in this example `widget.selectedTab(index)`

Full code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:animated_bottom_navigation_bar/animated_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
//! Import pages/tabs ...


// Home.dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _bottomNavIndex = 4;

  void selectedTab(index) {
    if (_bottomNavIndex != index) {
      setState(() {
        _bottomNavIndex = index;
      });
    }
  }


    Widget getBody() {
    List<Widget> pages = [
      const Page0(),
      const Page1(),
      const Page2(),
      // ...
      Page5(
        selectedTab: selectedTab,
      )
    ];
    return IndexedStack(
      index: _bottomNavIndex,
      children: pages,
    );
  }

    Widget getFooter() {
    List<IconData> iconItems = [
      Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
      Icons.stacked_bar_chart_outlined,
      Icons.account_balance_outlined,
      Icons.settings
      Icons.access_alarm,
      Icons.umbrella_outlined,
    ];

    return AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
      activeColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      inactiveColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      icons: iconItems,
      activeIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
      gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
      notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.softEdge,
      leftCornerRadius: 10,
      iconSize: 25,
      rightCornerRadius: 10,
      onTap: (index) {
        selectedTab(index);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: getBody(),
      floatingActionButton: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        onLongPress: () {
          selectedTab(4);
        },
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          elevation: 1,
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            selectedTab(5);
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: getFooter(),
    );
  }
}


// Page5.dart
class Page5 extends StatefulWidget {
 const Page5({Key? key,required this.selectedTab}) : super(key: key);
  
  
  //? Use type ValueSetter if passing a argument
  //? Use type ValueGtetter if you are not passing an argument but expecting a value to be returned
  //? Use type VoidCallback if not sending or receiving a value
  final ValueSetter<int> selectedTab;

  @override
  _Page5State createState() => _Page5State();
}

class _Page5State extends State<Page5> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            widget.selectedTab(0);
          },
          child: Text('Go Home')),
    );
  }
}
```